# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode when trying to write hebrew to a PDF

Tags: python, unicode, fpdf

im trying to write some hebrew words to a pdf file using the FPDF Libary in Python

and im getting an error

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 51-55: ordinal not in range(256)

how can i fix that and write hebrew to the PDF file?

adding my code below

```
     pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
    welcome="היייי"
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=welcome, ln=1, align="C")
    pdf.output("simple_demo.pdf")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `set_font` documentation:

> Standard fonts use Latin-1 encoding by default, (...)

and

> Default encoding is not specified, but all text writing methods accept only Unicode for external fonts and one byte encoding for standard.

Your `Arial` is a standard family, so it accept only `Latin-1` encoding (1 byte). So you should change font, with a non standard one, in order to have a Unicode fonts, so in order to get Hebrew text.

Comment: ok thanks for explaining it !
i will try to search for a font but gonna be a first time doing it 
any pointers?

Comment: OK i have found out the font folders in my pc and one of the fonts works! im gonna copy one font from there to the project directory!
thanks for the help!

Comment: @yishairasowsky: check Google fonts website (you have so many). If I remember correctly, the "standard fonts" are just few (and old: the special behaviour is just for compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

see this example: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Unicode/index.html

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

# Add a DejaVu Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
# Supports more than 200 languages. For a coverage status see:
# http://dejavu.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dejavu/trunk/dejavu-fonts/langcover.txt
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('DejaVu', '', 14)

text = u"""
English: Hello World
Greek: Γειά σου κόσμος
Polish: Witaj świecie
Portuguese: Olá mundo
Russian: Здравствуй, Мир
Vietnamese: Xin chào thế giớia
Arabic: مرحبا العالم
Hebrew: שלום עולם
"""
```